# Issues understanding gather function in tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm having some issues understanding  the `gather` function of `tidyr`. I have the following dataframe:

```
tidyv1 <- data.frame(name=c("Jake","Alice","Tim","Denise"),
                age=c(34,55,76,19),
                brown=c(0,0,1,0),
                blue=c(0,1,0,0),
                other=c(1,0,0,1),
                height=c(6.1,5.9,5.7,5.1))
```

I would like to take columns `brown:other` and make them one variable. Here is my code:

```
tidyc1 <- gather(tidyv1, key=eye_color, value=val, brown:other, factor_key=TRUE)
```

The outcome is this:

```
     name age height eye_color val
1    Jake  34    6.1     brown   0
2   Alice  55    5.9     brown   0
3     Tim  76    5.7     brown   1
4  Denise  19    5.1     brown   0
5    Jake  34    6.1      blue   0
6   Alice  55    5.9      blue   1
7     Tim  76    5.7      blue   0
8  Denise  19    5.1      blue   0
9    Jake  34    6.1     other   1
10  Alice  55    5.9     other   0
11    Tim  76    5.7     other   0
12 Denise  19    5.1     other   1
```

The outcome that I'm expecting is this:

```
    name age eye_color height
1   Jake  34     other    6.1
2  Alice  55      blue    5.9
3    Tim  76     brown    5.7
4 Denise  19     other    5.1
```

I'm aware that can be easily fix with extra code, but I want to understand if there is a direct way. For instance:

```
tidyc1[which(tidyc1[,5]==1),1:4]
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a direct way built into `gather`.  If you had `NA` instead of `0` you would get a lot closer, though, due to the `na.rm` argument.

Answer (score 3):

`gather` rearranges data by melting column names into one row and values into another, but doesn't drop data. In `tidyv1`, you have data that tells that people *don't* have certain eye colors, as well as that they do, all of which is kept by `gather`. If you have `NA`s instead, you can use `na.rm = TRUE`, but you'll still end up with an extra `val` column.

Thus, `gather` itself doesn't directly do what you want. You can clean up after the fact with

```
tidyc1[tidyc1$val == 1, -5]
```

...or inline with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
tidyv1 %>% gather(key=eye_color, value=val, brown:other, factor_key=TRUE) %>% 
    filter(val == 1) %>% select(-val)
```

...or just do the whole operation with `dplyr`:

```
tidyv1 %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(eye_color = c('brown', 'blue', 'other')[which(c(brown, blue, other) == 1)]) %>% 
    select(-brown:-other)
```

...or with base:

```
tidyv1$eye_color <- apply(tidyv1[,c('brown', 'blue', 'other')], 1, 
                          function(x){c('brown', 'blue', 'other')[x == 1]})
tidyv1 <- tidyv1[,-3:-5]
```

You end up with the same thing regardless of which you use, so pick your favorite.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.